# Problems applying a Sklearn ML model to a datraframe pandas with multiple columns and data types

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I need to predict the data from several columns of the pandas dataframe (ml_train_inputs), where there could be columns with several data types, for example: str, float, int, timestamp, etc. In this example, I have tried to prepare the data, as it is done for the model training where I used SKlearn and SVC, before applying the prediction and creating a new column "Predictions".

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'City': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo', 'Moscow', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Beijing', 'Shanghai', 'Sydney', 'Melbourne', 'Dubai', 'Singapore', 'Hong Kong', 'Seoul', 'Mumbai', 'Mexico City', 'São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro'],
        'Country': ['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'France', 'Japan', 'Russia', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'China', 'China', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Singapore', 'China', 'South Korea', 'India', 'Mexico', 'Brazil', 'Brazil'],
        'Population': [8175133, 8278000, 2148000, 13350000, 11920000, 3999759, 2718782, 2296193, 21500000, 24150000, 5000000, 4900000, 3320000, 5612000, 7347000, 51190000, 12690000, 21010000, 21295000, 6453000],
        'GDP per Capita': [162400, 406000, 40100, 379000, 25200, 60100, 45400, 57400, 16300, 28100, 53400, 44600, 62700, 92400, 64400, 28300, 5200, 9300, 11400, 8800]
       }

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data)

start_date = '2022-01-01'
end_date = '2022-12-31'
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
df_test['date'] = np.random.choice(date_range, size=len(df_test))

train_x = df_test
#ml_train_inputs = "['date', 'GDP per Capita', 'Country']" # possible
ml_train_inputs = "['date']"
ml_train_labels = "['Country']"

# Create list
ml_train_inputs_list = ml_train_inputs.strip("[]")
ml_train_inputs_list = [col.strip("'") for col in ml_train_inputs_list.split(",")]
ml_train_labels_list = ml_train_labels.strip("[]")
ml_train_labels_list = [col.strip("'") for col in ml_train_labels_list.split(",")]


# Identify columns with different data types
is_string_column = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].dtypes.apply(lambda x: x == 'object')
is_float_column = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].dtypes.apply(lambda x: x == 'float')
is_int_column = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].dtypes.apply(lambda x: x == 'int')
is_date_column = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].dtypes.apply(lambda x: x == 'datetime64[ns]')

# Create separate lists for string and float columns
string_columns = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].columns[is_string_column].to_list()
float_columns = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].columns[is_float_column].to_list()
int_columns = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].columns[is_int_column].to_list()
date_columns = train_x[ml_train_inputs_list].columns[is_date_column].to_list()

# Preprocess the string columns
if string_columns:
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
    train_x_string = train_x[string_columns]
    train_x_string_vector = tfidf.fit_transform(train_x_string.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1).values)
    test_x_string = test_x[string_columns]
    test_x_string_vector = tfidf.transform(test_x_string.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1).values)

# Preprocess the float columns
if float_columns:
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    train_x_float = train_x[float_columns]
    train_x_float = scaler.fit_transform(train_x_float)
    test_x_float = test_x[float_columns]
    test_x_float = scaler.transform(test_x_float)

# Preprocess the int columns
if int_columns:
  from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
  scaler = StandardScaler()
  train_x_int = train_x[int_columns]
  train_x_int = scaler.fit_transform(train_x_int)
  test_x_int = test_x[int_columns]
  test_x_int = scaler.transform(test_x_int)

if date_columns:
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
    train_x_date = ohe.fit_transform(train_x[date_columns])
    test_x_date = ohe.transform(test_x[date_columns])

if string_columns and float_columns and int_columns and date_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_string_vector.toarray(), train_x_float, train_x_int, train_x_date), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_string_vector.toarray(), test_x_float, test_x_int, test_x_date), axis=1)
elif string_columns and float_columns and int_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_string_vector.toarray(), train_x_float, train_x_int), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_string_vector.toarray(), test_x_float, test_x_int), axis=1)
elif string_columns and float_columns and date_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_string_vector.toarray(), train_x_float, train_x_date), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_string_vector.toarray(), test_x_float, test_x_date), axis=1)
elif int_columns and date_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_int, train_x_date), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_int, test_x_date), axis=1)
elif string_columns and int_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_string_vector.toarray(), train_x_int), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_string_vector.toarray(), test_x_int), axis=1)
elif string_columns and date_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_string_vector.toarray(), train_x_date), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_string_vector.toarray(), test_x_date), axis=1)
elif float_columns and int_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_float, train_x_int), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_float, test_x_int), axis=1)
elif float_columns and date_columns:
    train_x_vector = np.concatenate((train_x_float, train_x_date), axis=1)
    test_x_vector = np.concatenate((test_x_float, test_x_date), axis=1)
elif string_columns:
    train_x_vector = train_x_string_vector
    test_x_vector = test_x_string_vector
elif float_columns:
    train_x_vector = train_x_float
    test_x_vector = test_x_float
elif int_columns:
    train_x_vector = train_x_int
    test_x_vector = test_x_int
elif date_columns:
    train_x_vector = train_x_date
    test_x_vector = test_x_date

new_df = df_test
predictions = best_model.predict(train_x_vector)
new_df["Predictions"] = predictions
```

but I got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-54-1f6c5a970910> in <module>
     99 
    100 new_df = df_test
--> 101 predictions = best_model.predict(train_x_vector)
    102 new_df["Predictions"] = predictions
    103 

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    398 
    399         if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
--> 400             raise ValueError(
    401                 f"X has {n_features} features, but {self.__class__.__name__} "
    402                 f"is expecting {self.n_features_in_} features as input."

ValueError: X has 19 features, but SVC is expecting 15 features as input.
```

In short, I am trying to be consistent with the trained ml model, where there could be several column types and data types to apply to the respective dataframe.

I tried to make the code work with loops, but it didn't work either.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: This error effectively means exactly what it is saying: Model was trained on 15 columns but you're trying to test with an input that has 19 columns. It's unclear how you trained your model but clearly, it was trained on a different kind of data than the test input. Difficult to point out the issue unless the model training code was available

Comment: As a side note, based on the contents of the string variables you provide, I don't think tfidf makes any sense to use.  TfIdf is for *documents* in the sense that the feature contains *lots* of words.  I've seen it used where, e.g., the feature is "an entire resume".  It's not for things like countries.  Use one hot, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear what `best_model` is. However, it seems that you fit your model with a dataset containing 15 features and now are trying to predict with a dataset containing 19 features. I think this is what user betelgeuse commented.

Here is a minimal example of why the error is being generated, using the official example from sklearn's SVC [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) -

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(gamma='auto')
clf.fit(X, y)
```

As you can see here the dataset has 2 features. You can verify this by doing -

```
print("The number of features that X has = ", X.shape[1])
```

Now, if I do this -

```
print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1, 3,4,5]]))
```

I get the following error -

```
ValueError: X has 5 features, but SVC is expecting 2 features as input.
```